# how to retrieve the name of a file as a command argument and open it with open()

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, filenames, sys

I want to run my script on the command line and put as argument the name of the file on which I want to run my python script.
This is what I want to enter on the command line:

```
./pavage_dataframe.py 4.A.2.txt
```

I would like to get the filename (4.A.2.txt) and open it with open().
I think it's possible to use "sys" but I haven't quite figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as

```
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
```

The first element of `sys.argv` list is a name of the script itself, followed by command line arguments you have passed

Comment: Thank you for your help. For the sake of comprehension, can you explain to me why you have to put [1] please?

Comment: To get the first command line argument you need to retrieve the second item of sys.args list which have an index 1